# iOS: why this instance deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, crash, cocos2d-iphone

the code is :

```
if(!spriteInfoBack){
        spriteInfoBack = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_player.png"];
        [spriteInfoBack setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 1)];
        [spriteInfoBack setPosition:CGPointMake(infoLeftX, infoTopY)];
        [parent addChild:spriteInfoBack];
}else{
        [spriteInfoBack setPosition:CGPointMake(infoLeftX, infoTopY)];
}
```

The crash output is:

```
[CCSprite setPosition:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc59cc70
```

and it is positioned on this line:

```
[spriteInfoBack setPosition:CGPointMake(infoLeftX, infoTopY)];
```

I think it is strange, because the if(!spriteInfoBack) has already checked the instance is deallocated or not.

Comment: can u provide the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the `CCSprite`. The class method `spriteWithFile` returns an autoreleased object. The return value stored in `spriteInfoBack` is not owned by you. That means that the lifetime of the object is until the next autorelease pool is drained. From your code it appears that you are using `spriteInfoBack` as something that is lazy initialized and then used later. What you will want to do is retain the return value of `spriteWithFile` like so:

```
spriteInfoBack = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_player.png"] retain];
```

And at some future point you will need to release `spriteInfoBack`. I don't see the rest of the class but if `spriteInfoBack` is an instance variable of a class then doing so in the `dealloc` would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the `!spriteInfoBack` just check the value against `nil` (i.e. : `spriteInfoBlack == nil`), which is different (if you need to persuade yourself, log something in the `else` part).  The variable still contains a memory address and thus the crash because the instance has been deallocated.

We can't guess by looking at the code why the instance is deallocated, so double check the code, memory managment, and/or put `nil` in the variable once you don't need it anymore, this way you ensure the test won't fail.

Comment: so, if !spriteInfoBack cannot be use to check dealloc, how to check it?

Comment: you will not want to check that, unless you are not sure about your memory managment. If you follow them, *you know* when your object is deallocated.

Comment: i check dealloc because i want to do a lazy initialize.

Comment: again, lazy initialization has nothing to do here. Follow the memory managment rules, and you will be ok. At first, put `nil` in the var, and check with your if test if it is already alloc/init

Answer (score 0):

The instance is on the autorelease pool which is drained between iterations of the ui's event loop. If you want an object to survive the autorelease pool, you must explicitly retain/release the objects yourself. Even though the object has been deallocated (since you haven't retained it), the pointer `spriteInfoBack` still remembers the old address of the object.